# Does Nancy Token Authentication work with Web Load Balancers?

Tags: authentication, load-balancing, restful-authentication, nancy

I want to use token authentication in Nancy:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Token-Authentication

However documentation does not mention Load Balancers, and using with Load Balancers is a must for our application and architecture.

Would Nancy Token Authentication behave well with Web Load Balancers?

Answer (score 2):

By default - no. According to the link, keys used for generating the tokens are stored in local file "keyChain.bin". In order to support the load balanced environment you need to provide your own implementation of ITokenizer interface.

Comment: Agreed by default no. According to the doc https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Token-Authentication it talks about the InMemoryTokenKeystore which might work depending on your requirements, or, could possibly implement your own token keystore (e.g. https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Authentication.Token/Storage/InMemoryTokenKeyStore.cs) to store tokens in a shared cache instead of memory.